# How to make a table function on a dataframe based on a series of subsets - and then visualise specific values of the resulted tables?

Tags: r, dataframe, datatables, subset

I have these many datasets : df as the main data frame (but let's imagine all of them as very big datasets)

```
df = data.frame(x = seq(1,20,2),
y = c('a','a','b','c','a','a','b','c','a','a'),
z = c('d','e','e','d','f','e','e','d','e','f') )

g = data.frame(xx = c(2,3,4,5,7,8,9) )

h = data.frame(xx = c(3,5,7,8,9) )

i = data.frame(xx = c(2,3,6,8) )

j = data.frame(xx = c(1,3,6) )
```

And I wish to make a group of tables of frequency to the y column of df using the xx of each other dataframe each time (xx is used to subset df).

And then making  a group of tables of frequency to the Z column of df using the xx of each other dataframe each time (xx is used to subset df).

Next :

I would like to visualise the frequencies of each value for one variable to study its developpement :

for example : for variable y : the developpement of the value **a** going from g to j is : 2 2 1 2. I would like to visualise this developpement for each value of variable y in a simple way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could place the datasets in a `list` (`dplyr::lst`- returns a named list), loop over the `list` with `map`, subset the main dataset based on the 'x' column or do a `inner_join` and get the frequency `count`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(lst(g, h, i,j), 
   ~ inner_join(df, .x, by = c("x" = "xx")) %>%      
       count(y, name = 'Count'))
```

-output

```
$g
  y Count
1 a     2
2 b     1
3 c     1

$h
  y Count
1 a     2
2 b     1
3 c     1

$i
  y Count
1 a     1

$j
  y Count
1 a     2
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
lapply(list(g = g, h = h, i = i, j = j),
  \(dat) subset(df, x %in% dat$xx, select = y ) |>
      table())
```

---

If we need to visualize, either convert to a single dataset and then do the barplot with `geom_col/geom_bar` or use `barplot` in base R

```
library(ggplot2)
map_dfr(lst(g, h, i,j), 
   ~ inner_join(df, .x, by = c("x" = "xx")) %>%      
       count(y, name = 'Count'), .id = 'grp') %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = grp, y = Count, fill = y)) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

Comment: Thanks, but my bad that my question wasn't clear enough. when subsetting the dataset, I want the resulted dataframe to be converted into tables of frequencies. for example for the new g dataframe, variable y includes : 2 a - 1 b - 1 c. and I want each variable y and z alone. not both of them together. Thanks again

Comment: @Anas116 try the update

Comment: thanks a lot. that's what I want. To avoid confusion for other readers : let's change the name Z at the end of your function  into count

Comment: please check the added question @akrun

Comment: @Anas116 perhaps add `barplot` at the end i.e. `lapply(list(g = g, h = h, i = i, j = j),
  \(dat) subset(df, x %in% dat$xx, select = y ) |>
      table() |> barplot() )` and for the first one, you can use `%>% ggplot(aes(x = y, y = Count)) + geom_col())`

Comment: @Anas116 pleae check the update